# Optaplanner Score Corruption Using Bavet

Tags: optaplanner

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption ([30]hard/[0/30]soft): the workingScore (-3init/[-1850]hard/[-1/-1190]soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (-3init/[-1880]hard/[-1/-1220]soft) after completedAction (TWC(20301005) {TWC(20301008) -> TWC(20301008)}):

Hello, I got this error when running Vehicle Routing Solution. I didn't know what is the meaning of `after completedAction (TWC(20301005) {TWC(20301008) -> TWC(20301008)}):`.

TWC is TimeWindowCustomer, and have previousStandstill. But why Optaplanner change into same PlanningEntity TWC(20301008) -> TWC(20301008) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's leave aside the move itself - the reason why such a useless move is being executed is probably a bug. But even then there shouldn't be a score corruption; it's just an inefficient behavior.

If, when you use the default constraint stream implementation (`DROOLS`), the score corruption disappears, please file a bug report for us, with some code we can execute to reproduce the problem. Make sure you are using the latest version of OptaPlanner.

If the problem is still there even when using `DROOLS`, the problem is likely in your domain model.

Comment: I have looked up the ordering of Construction Heuristic. After trying a move, they have unmove. And before CH picked up "best move", CH will trigger VariableListener to all entity exist (even the entity isn't impact at all). Why this happen?